# When retrieving JSON data from SQLite back slash is showing up in the array

Tags: android, arrays, json, sqlite, android-cursor

When retrieving JSON data from SQLite , escape character "\" is showing up in the array. Initially I created the JSON array in Web-view javascript which then send to Android java to save in DB.

Below is my JSON string which I am sending to Java.

```
adtMf = [{"companyId":"12004","employeeId":"11345","employeeName":"jaseem","employeeDepartment":"SalesExecutive","employeePosition":"Staff","itemMeasurementNotes":"Notes here","itemMeasurementOwner":"someone","Items":"Shirt?ShirtPrice:1.1!ShirtQty:1.1!ShirtLength:2.12!ShirtShoulder:1.12!ShirtSleeveL:3.12!ShirtSleeveW:5.14!ShirtSleeveCuff:2.12!ShirtChest:3.12!ShirtBelly:4.12!ShirtSeat:5.12!ShirtCollar:5.12!ShirtSlideL1:4.1!ShirtSlideL2:4.12!ShirtSlideL3:2.4!"}]
android.addMeasurement(JSON.stringify(adtMf));
```

Below is my android code , which gets the data and saves to DB

```
 @JavascriptInterface
public void updateMeasurement(String response) {
    db.addADTMeasurement(response.toString());
}

public void addADTMeasurement(String ADTMeasurment) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(KEY_ADTMEASUREMENT, ADTMeasurment); 
    // Inserting Row
    long id = db.insert(TABLE_MYMEASUREMENT, null, values);
    Log.d(TAG, "New Measurement into sqlite: " + id);
}
```

After retrieving the data from SQLite, the JSON array is having "\". How do I remove that ? while adding to SQLite doesn't my code is adding "\" ? . For some weird reason the Android device manager file explorer is not working and so I am not able to confirm how the data is stored in DB.

Below is the android code used for retriving the data from DB

```
 public Cursor fetchADTMeasurement() {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor mCursor = db.query(TABLE_MYMEASUREMENT, new String[] {KEY_ADTMEASUREMENT},
            null, null, null, null, null);
    if (mCursor != null) {
        mCursor.moveToFirst();
    }
    return mCursor;
}

 Cursor mycursor2 = db.fetchADTMeasurement();
 JSONArray resultSet3 = new JSONArray();
 mycursor2.moveToFirst();
 String id = mycursor2.getString( mycursor2.getColumnIndex("ADTMeasurement") );
 while (mycursor2.isAfterLast() == false) {
    int totalColumn = mycursor2.getColumnCount();
    JSONObject rowObject = new JSONObject();
    for (int i = 0; i < totalColumn; i++) {
        if (mycursor2.getColumnName(i) != null) {
            try {
                resultSet3.put(mycursor2.getString(i));
                } catch (Exception e) { }
          }
      }
      mycursor2.moveToNext();
     }
     mycursor2.close();
    super.onPageFinished(view, url);
    if (url.equals("file:///android_asset/myMeasurments_a.html")) {
                   myWebView.loadUrl("javascript:start("+resultSet3+");");
                }
```

When I out put the resultSet3 in javascript. I am getting the "\" next to all the string.

```
function start(d){
    adtMf = d.slice();
    console.log(JSON.stringify(adtMf));
}

I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(42)] "["[{\"companyId\":12004,\"employeeId\":\"11345\",\"employeeName\":\"jaseem\",\"employeeDepartment\":\"SalesExecutive\",\"employeePosition\":\"Staff\",\"itemMeasurementNotes\":\"Notes here\",\"itemMeasurementOwner\":\"someone\",\"Items\":\"Shirt?ShirtPrice:1.1!ShirtQty:1.1!ShirtLength:2.12!ShirtShoulder:1.12!ShirtSleeveL:3.12!ShirtSleeveW:5.14!ShirtSleeveCuff:2.12!ShirtChest:3.12!ShirtBelly:4.12!ShirtSeat:5.12!ShirtCollar:5.12!ShirtSlideL1:4.1!ShirtSlideL2:4.12!ShirtSlideL3:2.4!\"}]"]"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this if you want to remove backslashes from the json:

```
   String newJsonString = jsonString.replaceAll("\\\\", "");
```

Comment: it doesn't work. While adding the above code using my json array it is showing in red.

Comment: Hi @user1846348, I have posted answer please check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49221937/when-retrieving-json-data-from-sqlite-back-slash-is-showing-up-in-the-array/49238716#49238716)

Answer (score 0):

the below code worked for me

```
Cursor mycursor2 = db.fetchADTMeasurement();
mycursor2.moveToFirst();
String resultSet3 = mycursor2.getString(0);
mycursor2.close();

super.onPageFinished(view, url);
if (url.equals("file:///android_asset/myMeasurments_a.html")) {
    myWebView.loadUrl("javascript:start("+resultSet3+");");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have tried this using the following code hope it may help you

```
String jsonString="[{\\\"companyId\\\":12004,\\\"employeeId\\\":\\\"11345\\\",\\\"employeeName\\\":\\\"jaseem\\\",\\\"employeeDepartment\\\":\\\"SalesExecutive\\\",\\\"employeePosition\\\":\\\"Staff\\\",\\\"itemMeasurementNotes\\\":\\\"Notes here\\\",\\\"itemMeasurementOwner\\\":\\\"someone\\\",\\\"Items\\\":\\\"Shirt?ShirtPrice:1.1!ShirtQty:1.1!ShirtLength:2.12!ShirtShoulder:1.12!ShirtSleeveL:3.12!ShirtSleeveW:5.14!ShirtSleeveCuff:2.12!ShirtChest:3.12!ShirtBelly:4.12!ShirtSeat:5.12!ShirtCollar:5.12!ShirtSlideL1:4.1!ShirtSlideL2:4.12!ShirtSlideL3:2.4!\\\"}]";
Log.e("jsonString=",jsonString);
String newJsonString = jsonString.replaceAll("\\\\", "");
Log.e("newJsonString=",newJsonString);
```

console log: jsonString is

```
jsonString=: [{\"companyId\":12004,\"employeeId\":\"11345\",\"employeeName\":\"jaseem\",\"employeeDepartment\":\"SalesExecutive\",\"employeePosition\":\"Staff\",\"itemMeasurementNotes\":\"Notes here\",\"itemMeasurementOwner\":\"someone\",\"Items\":\"Shirt?ShirtPrice:1.1!ShirtQty:1.1!ShirtLength:2.12!ShirtShoulder:1.12!ShirtSleeveL:3.12!ShirtSleeveW:5.14!ShirtSleeveCuff:2.12!ShirtChest:3.12!ShirtBelly:4.12!ShirtSeat:5.12!ShirtCollar:5.12!ShirtSlideL1:4.1!ShirtSlideL2:4.12!ShirtSlideL3:2.4!\"}]
```

console log: newJsonString is

```
newJsonString=: [{"companyId":12004,"employeeId":"11345","employeeName":"jaseem","employeeDepartment":"SalesExecutive","employeePosition":"Staff","itemMeasurementNotes":"Notes here","itemMeasurementOwner":"someone","Items":"Shirt?ShirtPrice:1.1!ShirtQty:1.1!ShirtLength:2.12!ShirtShoulder:1.12!ShirtSleeveL:3.12!ShirtSleeveW:5.14!ShirtSleeveCuff:2.12!ShirtChest:3.12!ShirtBelly:4.12!ShirtSeat:5.12!ShirtCollar:5.12!ShirtSlideL1:4.1!ShirtSlideL2:4.12!ShirtSlideL3:2.4!"}]
```